# Why are LibreOffice 5.2 menus flickering in Xubuntu 16.04?

Tags: xubuntu, libreoffice

LibreOffice 5.2 menus are flickering when opening LibreOffice and while hovering the mouse over them. After a while the flickering fades away. Very annoying and nerve breaking. I guess it got something to do with loading the program into RAM memory. Is there anything i can do about that flickering? This doesn't happen in Windows or in Wine.

Comment: I have this problem with v5.3.2.2 x64 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

This solved it for me, on v5.3 / Windows 10 / x64:

1. Tools > Options...
2. Enable "Use OpenGL for all rendering"
3. Quit and restart LibreOffice

Comment: Yes, I know this is an Ubuntu forum, but this might help universally.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and had quick look into it.
It appears that turning off compositing fixes this issue.

Settings Manager > Window Manager Tweaks > Compositor > disable "enable display compositing"

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, my system input method was set to `xim`. Unsetting it and allowing it to default to `ibus` finally fixed it.

See https://askubuntu.com/a/1434282/133818